# Tabulator: Access to columns with keyboard

Tags: tabulator

I am trying to create a table using the Tabulator library, and I'm encountering a problem with accessibility.

Using any of the examples on the Tabulator site which have column sorting, I need to tab into the column and use the space bar or enter key to sort the column (simulating a click or a touch). However, I am unable to use keyboard to access the columns - it appears that only a mouse click is possible.

Are there any settings when declaring my columns that I can use to gain keyboard accessibility to the columns?

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not built in at present, If you would like to see the functionality added to the library please create a [Feature Request](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Suggested+Feature&template=feature_request.md&title=)